# Import module name conflict in Django

Tags: python, django

I've a project with the following directory structure:

```
prj 
|--- app_a
|--- app_b
       |---- app_a
```

Inside app_b I've a tests.py module where I define tests. So far so good, problem is I need to evaluate `import app_a` and get prj.app_a but I get prj.app_b.app_a instead. I tried using relative imports just to try as a workaround and I get:

> ValueError: Attempted relative import beyond toplevel package

Is it possible to solve this issue without renaming any directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you're on Python 2; in Python 3 the ambiguity between absolute and relative imports is solved—see [PEP 328](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/) for more detail.

You can achieve the same thing in Python 2 by using `from __future__ import absolute_import`. Once you do that, `import app_a` will be an absolute import and will refer to the top-level package. You can then access the other one with an absolute `from app_b import app_a` or a relative `from . import app_a`.

Comment: You're right, thank you very much for answering and also for improving the English grammar on the question. Before posting the question i tried using __future__ but i got an error which I misunderstood.